# How to delete/free up memory allocated to an NLog logger

Tags: c#, .net, logging, nlog

The requirement is to create one log file per job and multiple jobs can run concurrently.

I've implemented this with NLog by creating a new target, new logger and new rule per job. When I have 1000s of jobs running and completing at various times, how can I avoid memory leaks with all the extra logging resources allocated per job (logger/rule/target)? Is there a way to delete loggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not have any issues with leaking Logger-object, as NLog only holds weak-references. So the garbage collector is allowed to collect all NLog Logger objects not kept alive with object-references in the application.

But you will probably have to remove the dynamically create NLog-targets. You can use this method to remove a named-target:

```
NLog.LogManager.Configuration.RemoveTarget("myRandomTargetName");
```

The above method has been improved with NLog 4.5, so it can be used on the active LoggingConfiguration-object.

See also: https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.5.0/html/M_NLog_Config_LoggingConfiguration_RemoveTarget.htm

Comment: This clears things up, thanks! Do rules that apply to garbage collected loggers and removed targets also get deleted?

Comment: @ame Nope unused loggingrules are not removed automatically. NLog 4.6 allows you to create named-loggingrules that can be removed again: https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v4.6.0/html/M_NLog_Config_LoggingConfiguration_RemoveRuleByName.htm